How to do an OAuth 2.0 redirect URL with a dynamically generated URL, created with Cloud Run blue-green deployment
I have an app that integrates with an OAuth 2.0 provider (Entra ID). Entra ID requires a redirect URL to be used after the user successfully logs in.
My CI/CD does blue-green deployment with Cloud Run, and does the following:

It first deploys a "green" revision of this app. The green revision URL is dynamically generated, with the tag green-<cloud build buildID>, so that different builds running at the same time don't accidentally overwrite each other's green revision.
It runs Cypress on the green revision.
If the Cypress tests pass, then the green revision gets untagged and promoted to the blue revision, and is deployed onto my environment.

This blue-green deployment flow works well without Entra ID, but when using Entra ID things get a lot more complicated. Entra ID does not support wildcard redirect URLs, so I can't successfully use OAuth 2.0 with my "green" build URL because it is dynamically generated.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to deal with this? I'd prefer not to have my CI/CD have to dynamically update my Entra ID app registration with the green URL with every build.

Did solve this issue eventually?

Nope never figured it out, the product I was working on was discontinued so I never had to.
